# Set Visibility of TextView Background in CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am trying to position a TextView above an ImageView. Now I wish to Set the visibility of the TextView Background to 40%. This is my current Status.

```
...
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/framelayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="378dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:text="Caption"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="165dp"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </FrameLayout>
...
```

Can Someone Please Guide me, how Should I go about with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="378dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Caption"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"

    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

To adjust the transparency you must use `android:alpha=""` property, and text size is not in `dp` , its `sp` . hope it helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Well That was Helpful! Thank you so much.